# OllyDbg: Constant does not fit into operand

Tags: assembly, ollydbg

I'm trying to assemble this instruction:

[image]

I'm not being able to do it..

When I test with MOV AX,55000 I get this error:

[image]

I tested before in Cheat Engine, and this is working as AOB injection: MOV AX,#55000

So if I test with the same syntax, ollydbg can't recognize it:

[image]

I don't know how to assemble that instruction correctly:

MOV AX,55000 instead of MOV AX,WORD PTR DS:[EBX+A4]

In Cheat Engine it's working perfectly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OllyDbg is interpreting numbers as hex by default. But `0x55000` is larger than `0xFFFF` so it cannot be stored in a 16bit register, which `ax` is, hence it complains.

If you meant the decimal number 55000, I think you can enter it as "55000." with the trailing dot. If that doesn't work enter the number as hex:

```
mov ax, 0D6D8
```

The leading 0 is necessary otherwise the first character would be a letter and OllyDbg would not recognize it as a number.

Comment: thank you :) both options worked